# How to cancel validation check in standard Django registration view?

Tags: django

Good afternoon, please tell me how to cancel the standard form validation in the Django registration view, the is_valid method is responsible for this.

`   from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate

```
    def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/registration.html', {'form': form})`
```

I tried to remove the condition with it, so that in any case the data would be saved, but it gives an error:Exception Type: ValueError at /account/registration/
Exception Value: The CustomUser could not be created because the data didn't validate.

Comment: Please show your code for `CustomUserCreationForm` and your `CustomUser` model and the traceback from your console. Python tracebacks show you the line where your issue is

Comment: Please write your `forms.py` code and do you have a image or any file field in your form??